# "ERROR: there is no parameter $1" in "EXECUTE .. USING ..;" statement in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, ddl

I have a plpgsql function to create child tables using table inheritance in PostgreSQL like this:

```
CREATE TABLE parent_table (
  value integer,
  end_time timestamp without time zone
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mk_child(_year INTEGER, _month INTEGER)
  RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
  tname varchar;
  start_date date;
  end_date date;
  next_month varchar := (_month + 1)::text;
  next_year varchar := (_year + 1)::text;
BEGIN
  tname := 'child_y' || substring(_year::text from 3 for 2)
           || 'm' || lpad(_month::text, 2, '0');
  start_date := DATE (_year::text || '-' || _month::text || '-01');
  IF ( _month = 12 ) THEN
       end_date := DATE (next_year || '-01-01');
  ELSE
       end_date := DATE (_year::text || '-' || next_month || '-01');
  END IF;

  RAISE NOTICE 'Creating child table %', tname;
  EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE %I ( CHECK ( end_time >= %L AND end_time < %L))
                  INHERITS (parent_table)', tname, start_date, end_date);
  -- EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE %I ( CHECK ( end_time >= $1 AND end_time < $2))
  --                 INHERITS (parent_table)', tname)
  -- USING start_date, end_date;
  RETURN tname;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I call it, it is successful:

```
# select mk_child(2015,1);                                           
NOTICE:  Creating child table child_y15m01
   mk_child   
--------------
 child_y15m01
(1 row)
```

However, if I use the `EXECUTE ... USING ...;` form (commented out in the snippet above), I get an error:

```
# select mk_child(2015,2);
NOTICE:  Creating child table child_y15m02
ERROR:  there is no parameter $1
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "CREATE TABLE child_y15m02 ( CHECK ( end_time >= $1 AND end_time < $2 ) ) INHERITS (parent_table)"
PL/pgSQL function mk_child(integer,integer) line 21 at EXECUTE statement
```

[The PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) say explicitly that this format works and is more efficient.

So why does it not work as expected?

Comment: You can check good answer  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302098/pl-pgsql-there-is-no-parameter-1-in-execute-statement

Comment: @dezso: The problem is that you cannot parameterize the values of a `CHECK` constraint, since that is DDL code, even if it *looks* like a DML statement that can work with `USING`. ***This is a good question with a sneaky problem that should not have been closed***. I am addressing you since you are the only Postgres native in lynch mob - the rest seems to have followed your lead.

Comment: @Erwin reopened :)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yes, you are right - sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only pass values to DML statements. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

> Another restriction on parameter symbols is that they only work in
> `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` commands. In other statement types
> (generically called utility statements), you must insert values
> textually even if they are just data values.

So `CREATE TABLE` statement does not accept parameters via `USING` clause, even if expressions in a `CHECK` constraint *look* like values that might be parameterized.

That aside, you can largely simplify your function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mk_child(_year int, _month int)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
DECLARE
   start_date date := to_date(_year::text || _month::text, 'YYYYMM');
   tname text := to_char(start_date , '"child_y"YY"m"MM');
BEGIN
   RAISE NOTICE 'Creating child table %', tname;
   EXECUTE format('
      CREATE TABLE %I (CHECK (end_time >= %L AND end_time < %L))
      INHERITS (parent_table)'
    , tname, start_date, (start_date + interval '1 month')::date);
   RETURN tname;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Related:

- [Self-managing PostgreSQL partition tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7891629/939860)

If this is about table partitioning, look to the new **declarative table partitioning** in Postgres 10 or later. Related answer with sample code and links:

- [Better database for "keep always the 5 latest entries per ID and delete older"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186041/better-database-for-keep-always-the-5-latest-entries-per-id-and-delete-older/186085#186085)

Comment: Perhaps the error message could have been a little more informative. Thank you for your help and simplifications.

Comment: @donatello: Consider the added minor improvements.