# How to parametrize DDL in a plpgsql procedure?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, plpgsql, ddl

How do I parametrize DDL statements in a plpgsql procedure? Namely, I want to use the `org_label` param as the role and schema name but the code below takes it literally and I end up with the role "org_label":

```sql
create or replace procedure create_org_schema (org_label varchar(63)) -- max identifier len in pgsql is 63
language plpgsql AS $$ BEGIN
  create role org_label IN GROUP organization;
  GRANT org_label TO ardoq_api_customers; -- so that AUTHORIZATION... below works
  CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION org_label;
  SET ROLE org_label;
  GRANT USAGE on SCHEMA org_label to ardoq_api_customers; -- so that we can list it
  RESET ROLE;
END $$;
```

I have tried to change the first line to:

```sql
EXECUTE 'create role $1 IN GROUP organization' USING org_label;
```

But that fails with:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1" at character 13
> QUERY:  create role $1 IN GROUP organization
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **not**. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

> Another restriction on parameter symbols is that they only work in
> `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` commands. In other statement types
> (generically called utility statements), you must insert values
> textually even if they are just data values.

`EXECUTE .. USING` does not work for this. You have to concatenate the query string before executing. Typically, `format()` is most convenient to do that safely:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_org_schema (org_label varchar(63)) -- max identifier len in pgsql is 63
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format ('CREATE ROLE %I IN GROUP organization', org_label);
   -- ...
END
$func$;
```

Note the use of the format specifier `%I` to properly quote the *identifier* and defend against otherwise possible SQL injection. Use legal, lower-case names to keep your life with Postgres simple.

See:

- ["ERROR: there is no parameter $1" in "EXECUTE .. USING ..;" statement in plpgsql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121453/error-there-is-no-parameter-1-in-execute-using-statement-in-plpgsql/121549#121549)
- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/sql-injection-in-postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries)
- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860)